# An error message EXCLUSIVE ENQ for DSN is displayed while trying to transfer a file to a Mainframe system. Why is this so?

Tags: dataset, mainframe, file-transfer

An error message EXCLUSIVE ENQ for DSN is dosplayed while trying to transfer a file to a Mainframe system. Why is this so? Does this mean that the dataset is in use during transfer invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to transfer a dataset at the same time it is being used by another job. For a discussion of an issue that is most likely related to yours see [this message](http://www.mail-archive.com/ibm-main@bama.ua.edu/msg49226.html)

Answer (score 2):

Something has the dataset locked.  It could be a job, a user editing the dataset, a CICS region, or it could be transfer package itself.

Is the DSN you are sending to unique and only for the purposes of the specific transfer you are trying?  If it is not, that is, if other transfer processes might use that name and rely on scheduling to prevent conflicts, you will eventually have a problem.

Which transfer package are you using?  And can you post the specific error text?